# What "command" does Celery's app.control.broadcast expect?

Tags: python, django, celery

I thought that app.control.broadcast would take an @task, but when running the following:

```
app.send_task("workerTasks_supervisor.task_supervisor_test", args=[], queue='supervisor')

app.control.broadcast("workerTasks_supervisor.task_supervisor_test", args=[], queue="supervisor")
```

The first succeeds and the second fails with:

```
[2019-08-01 12:10:52,260: ERROR/MainProcess] pidbox command error: KeyError('task_supervisor_test',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 104, in dispatch
    reply = handle(method, arguments)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 126, in handle_cast
    return self.handle(method, arguments)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 120, in handle
    return self.handlers[method](self.state, **arguments)
KeyError: 'task_supervisor_test'
```

The worker is started with

```
celery worker -A workerTasks_supervisor -n Supervisor --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info -Q supervisor -f /logs/celery_supervisor.log --pidfile=/logs/supervisor_pid.pid
```

And the task itself is simple:

```
@app.task()
def task_supervisor_test():
    print("working")
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is wrong.

Your second line is trying to broadcast a command that you did not implement and it naturally throws an exception.

Beauty of Celery (among many things) is that it allows you to implement your own [commands](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#commands). You may execute them programmatically like you tried above, or through the command line via something like `celery -A my.project.app <command> [params...]`. It is an extremely powerful concept that I suggest every Celery power-user should learn about.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's a different set of things - you need to register them like this:

```
from celery.worker.control import Panel

@Panel.register
def command_supervisor_test():
    print("working")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the control module, you can find some examples.

```
from celery.app import control
```

as an example revoke function uses broadcast internally:

```
    def revoke(self, task_id, destination=None, terminate=False,
               signal=TERM_SIGNAME, **kwargs):
        return self.broadcast('revoke', destination=destination, arguments={
            'task_id': task_id,
            'terminate': terminate,
            'signal': signal,
        }, **kwargs)
```